# There's a person who can pass down his knowledge to someone else. How powerful would they actually be?

Tags: science-based, medieval

The dragon-blooded is a person who possesses the Power of the Dragons, despite not being one.

Dragons have an innate way to communicate with one another through long distances, this way is called "Paths" and this mesh of Paths forms a cloud that can be used to store and retrieve data.

The dragon-blooded is a part of this network allowing them to store information of their past lives inside of it. Skills, lexical knowledge and even genetic code.

Upon the expiration of the current holder, their body becomes a holy corpse that releases airborne particles. Sapient non-dragon beings that come into contact with the particles become candidates for the dragon-blooded to be reborn into.

A big downside (from a certain point of view) is that the chosen candidate's personality undergoes drastic changes as it parses through hundreds of years worth of memories. Much like with the Will of the First King from AoT, the new dragon-blooded becomes complacent with the will of its predecessors.

A dragon-blooded's body undergoes changes as well, rooting out errors and turning it into something that's capable of combat by swapping parts of the genetic code. Occasionally, the natural lifespan is extended so that a person's time as a dragon-blooded is at least 13 years.

There can be only one dragon-blooded at any times, however, the holy corpses and the candidates are still kept as a safety measure.

In paper the dragon-blooded is supposed to be the strongest (in terms of combat prowess) person in the <s>universe</s> world, however, **I'm not sure. How much they could do by themselves?**

**I'm going to limit this to combat, more precisely trial by combat and the chances of survival for a particular holder in a regular pitched battle (this time not Agincourt, that'd be too easy)**

Note about how this thing works: Time and patience, also, artificially induced coma while sleeping that allows the memories to sync up with the cloud. There's also work that has to be done with a person's memories, though that's handled by the cloud in the background.

Comment: I don't get what is your question

Comment: He seems to be asking about combat skill?

Comment: You're talking about the Dragonborn from Skyrim, right?

Comment: @F1Krazy Partly, though it's closer to the Avatar, except without the colossal-titan-size weakness.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica  is right. What exactly is your question? For example, there is no ? mark in your question. And the question in your title does not seem to match the text.

Comment: Is this like an Avatar thing?  The next one is born when his predecessor dies?

Comment: @hszmv Pretty much, except the Avatar state is constant here, so they're more like an Ackerman.

Comment: So one thing to be weary of is the sucessor will have all the memories to perform certain actions... but he's still got the body of the successor which will limit the abilities some what... for example, knowing everything about sword fighting from birth is powerful... but good luck being a master swordsman when you can't even support your own head, let alone lift a broadsword.

Comment: @hszmv Story-wise the first few dragon-blooded were autistic workaholics like Terry A. Davis, from as many fields as possible, giving the dragon-blooded much needed options and the ability to adapt to any situation. So they can always whip out Bear Grylls and switch to wandering samurai when the time comes.

Comment: @Mephistopheles:  That doesn't take into account that he will still run afoul of a case of "The Spirit is willing, the body is unable".   He knows how to do these things, but sometimes these skills come from not just mental training, but physical training.  He can have all the knowledge of a contortionist, but his new body might be a bit more stiff than what he's used to.  Some skills require knowledge and physical ability, for example, Stephen Hawking never had an IQ test, and had he taken it, he would have scored quite low+

Comment: @hszmv Sure, that's why genetic code is passed along, now get that pesky myostatin out of my face.

Comment: +It would definately be lower than my score.  That's not to say I'm smarter than Hawkings.. and I'll admit, I've never had a type of radiation named after me, so I'll probably say so.  But the IQ test does have physical components to it and is timed.   I'm not saying I'm smarter than Stephen Hawking... But I also do not currently suffer from ALS... which is where my advantage comes into play on an IQ test.

Comment: I don't think DNA works that way. Although it seems to me the skill chain could just make sure to only pick people in peak physical condition. Also, are bears considered sapient in this universe? Because I would pick a bear if I was the skill chain. Like after 200 years of fighting the extra skill learning capabilities of homo-sapiens don't see that great compared to claws.

Comment: well things keep changing, some past memory or knowledge may end up to be obsolete for the current timeline, can he forget such memory ?

Comment: Yes, the edit was a bad idea, rollback.

Answer (score 10):

**Waste of a Fighter, but a Master Strategist**

Fighting, combat especially, isn't about *knowledge* per se. Sure, a complete encyclopedic knowledge of all things combat would be a boon, and would tip the scales of two otherwise equal fighters. But fighting is more of a instinctual art, rather than a careful thought out one. Martial artists train repeatedly, not so they can learn the move mentally, but so the move is completely drilled into their instincts, their muscle memory. Not to mention the other factors at play, such as physical ability like height, strength, dexterity. Some people *are* just better than others, physically, and there exist gaps that no about of skill can cross. If you took an already incredible fighter and gave him these memories of centuries of combat, than it would improve him, certainly. And you'd end up with an exceptionally capable fighter, instead of a normal capable one.

But that's such a waste as to what it *could* be like. And that is the world's greatest mind. There's a character from Wheel of Time who inherits the memory of all the world's greatest generals, and that makes him the greatest military mind on the continent. If you gave this knowledge not to your strongest fighter, but your cleverest tactician, you could have a man with the combined skills of Alexander the Great, Hannibal of Barca, Julius Caesar, Sun Tzu ... and the list goes on literally throughout history. *That* is the strongest fighter you could have. Someone with centuries of experience waging war. Every victory, every defeat, every trick. That's the true power you're dealing with - not the potential for a great soldier, but the potential for a great army.

Comment: I made a distinction between skill and lexical knowledge and stated that both are passed down.

Comment: I don't mean to imply that this has to be one or the other. I'm just saying that it's a waste to give it a warrior when you could give it to a tactician. I suppose you could try having a half-warrior/half strategist, but specialization is better than generalization. You're better off focusing on one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

You have a vast trove of information and all you can think of is hitting people? That seems like an utter waste.

Someone with that kind of knowledge and experience would be an expert in never having to hit anyone. It's not how smart, wise people work : they would anticipate any conflict and take preventive measures far in advance. They would be everyone's wisest and most valued ally and advisor, and everyone would rush to defend them if there was a hint of a threat.

Answer (score 0):

> Everybody has a plan until they get punched in the mouth -- (Mike Tyson)

Assuming your holy corpses only choose particularly well suited physical specimens, I imagine they would have a good chance of producing some really impressive warriors. Some perks that it would enjoy:

- Obviously, high level experience in each and every martial art, as well as the time to explore the world and figure out which ones were BJJ and which were Mall-Kung-Fu.
- The experience of having been in many life-and-death situations. Most people only experience a handful of those at most, so we mostly panic and do stupid stuff. No matter what he sees, your guy has probably seen worse. The sort of once in a lifetime, shock indicing pain that would freeze up most people would be familiar and no longer shocking.
- A different goal while fighting. This one is questionable, because it depends on what you mean by "best,"but consider: your guy knows he's coming back if he dies. Therefore, the parameters that he's fighing in are different. For most people, getting killed is, like, a huge problem. Your warrior would be able to prioritize killing his enemy. He could lean on the classic "Haha, your sword is stuck in my chest, so you can't parry my next attack!" move.

On top of this, if your guy kept abreast tech of developments, he'd presumably have the best gear, etc. And if some of his generations were used to do engineering stuff, he could probably help design it.

I'd probably not deploy him to front line stuff, because there's only so much skill can do against a giant press of people. Instead, use him for special stuff -- assassinations, duels, etc. If he has to fight in a war, keep he's probably a pretty good morale boost, though.

Answer (score 0):

*The Question got edited to the extent that my answer does not make the most sense now.*

#### new answer:

**At this point it's up to you.**

Science got left behind quite a while ago, it's up to you how strong a dragon-blooded is. The theory behind it still makes it so that no matter how enhanced you get being a dragon-blooded, you are still just a single person. Nigh unbeatable in one on one combat but not undefeatable. Knowledge and strength do have limits (which you set) and there is not an infinite amount of actions in combat, which means in some situations there is no room to improve. A dragon-blooded fighter would win almost all the time but still could loose to a freak of nature, due to bad luck or just because last days ration of food had gone bad... you decide.

#### old answer:

> **Powerfull, but probably not to the extent that you would like it.**
>
> So you get chosen, get all that knowledge, ~13 years more to live and a full->!body, genetic overhaul. After the transition phase (I'd guess there is one), >!you essentially are a "perfect" human.
>
> Fastest reflexes possible, no physical faults, everything dialed up to the >!complete maximum any human can deliver. Some things are contradictory though >!and there is no "perfect" as different tasks would require different >!specializations (longer legs to torso ratio combined with thin legs and a slim >!overall build for sprinting / bigger sized upper torso for swimming etc.) (<-- >!not too sure if they are scientifically true but you get the point). So this >!mysterious force would figure out a shape best for every (combat)task. A middle >!ground through trial and error. Like super sped up evolution. Still pretty neat >!though.
>
> In single combat, such a person would likely dominate.
> The fewer variables are involved the more beneficial the enhancements get. If >!it is just enhanced fighter [A] vs regular human [B] in a controlled and fair >!environment... [A] will win.
>
> Except that's not how most fights will go down. Like you asked, e.g. in a large >!scale battle your enhanced person is just one piece to the puzzle. Multiple >!people are involved, terrain, weather, numbers, weapons used, army composition >!the list of variables keeps going.
> So this enhanced person will get the highest chance of survival a single person >!can get in such situations, which is still quite low. Perfect vision, perfect >!situational awareness, etc. are all good but a human has limits and for >!example, is barely able to evade an arrow. What if due to factors that cannot >!be influenced by that one person, a 1 VS 5 fight in the middle of the >!battlefield takes place? Good luck.. being singled out, 2 to 3 fighters >!directly engage you while the others wait for their opportunity to catch you >!when you can't evade, oh and one of them constantly shoots arrows at you. There >!is no martial arts move to get out of that situation alive.
>
> As others pointed out it would be a waste for such a person to take part in >!basically any direct fighting. If there is a fight, that person would 'just' >!get the best/close to the best outcome one single human can achieve. Which >!might not always be enough to get out of it alive/unscathed.
>
> **Just saw the science-based tag after writing my answer.** There is no known >!way such a thing could work. Transforming a body does work but the extent >!described would go beyond any DNA technology available to us and I don't think >!changing bone structure is possible. Passing on knowledge and muscle-memory >!through DNA? That's somewhere between FTL spaceships and time-travel, you make >!up your own rules in that territory.

Comment: Except that never was the case, though I blame edits for that.

Comment: @Mephistopheles changed the answer, at this point I'd say it is completely up to you. Set up general rules and stay consistent with them. If you need any values based on reality look up what individual people managed to do in terms of sports/combat and your dragon-blooded should be able to do all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In fiction, there are two commonly used types of combat/battles (tropes):

- Traditional combat: This is closest to real world combat. Large amounts of soldiers do things like form battle lines, move in platoons, preform cavalry charges, etc. If there are rifles, this eventually transforms into modern military squad-based tactics. The individual is a cog in the machine and designed to be replaced with minimal hassle.
- Hero or Named combat: Super-powered individuals (often magic users) determine the outcome of a fight. Typically, soldiers are just the backdrop for the actual powerhouses to duke it out. When one of the super-powered individuals wins, their side wins because the super-powered individuals are individually strong enough to slaughter regular grunts by the hundreds.

From what you've described, the dragon-blooded individuals don't sound like they could participate in Named combat. While they might be at peak human performance and a master of every martial art, you need to be superhuman to with a fight against an army as an individual. Putting an individual like this on the front lines of a traditional battlefield would be a waste as while they might be able to kill more people than the average soldier (but not by much), their real value is their memory, wisdom, and experience. The dragon-blooded is just as likely to get killed by a stray arrow as anyone else.

Fighting or realistic combat is also much less glorious or structured than you think. In an unstructured fight, even a beginner can win against a master. There is no rule of fighting which states that the better fighter always wins. Even if you've mastered every martial art, you could still slip on a pebble and be killed.

The only place I can see that a dragon-blooded individual would be unbeatable/extremely formidable is if you place them in a ritualized, structured combat environment such as in an "honor-duel" or something like that. This transforms the challenge into one of killing into one of skill.

Dragon-blooded individuals would be much better suited as generals, strategists, politicians, or managers. All of these roles would benefit exponentially more from multiple lifetimes of experience compared to a warrior.

Comment: So, trial by combat? Fighting in stead of a dwarf?

Answer (score 0):

What could a dragon-blooded do by themselves?

As Halfthawed pointed out, they would be *king* of strategy. Assuming not only knowledge but certain mental skills are passed down, your dragon-blooded will be able to visualize the entire battlefield, analyze his vision, form a plan, and then execute it. As Eric Nylund said in Resistors: "Superior long-term tactics always win over superior short-term tactics."

This person will see the battlefield as a chessboard, and he will be a grandmaster, the best chess player in the entire world. However, as David Hambling pointed out, he may not *need* to fight: "Someone with that kind of knowledge and experience would be an expert in never having to hit anyone. It's not how smart, wise people work : they would anticipate any conflict and take preventive measures far in advance."

The dragon-blooded's greatest strength is not in combat but in *leadership*; powerful leaders bring out the potential in someone else, giving them vision and helping them become part of something bigger than themselves. The right person can cause a ripple effect in society itself; sure, one person can't move a mountain, but as a leader, you can get an *entire nation* to work with you and move that mountain!

However, I must note that "airborne particles" from the holy corpse of the last dragon-blooded are what enable the inheritance of the dragon-blooded trait. If you *were* to remove the "only one candidate can become a dragon-blooded" rule, *then* you'd have an army of extremely wise, combat-optimal soldiers who (as Zwuwdz pointed out) would *not* panic or do something stupid when in a surprising or intense situation, and would *not* fear death.

In that case, I would suggest there being one 'special' dragon-blooded who acts as the king, and any number of other 'soldier-class' dragon-blooded who fight for the king and spread the 'glory of the dragons.' Sort of a variation of the whole zombie theme; these guys will be trying to bring about a new, better world, where everyone has the experience and knowledge of ages and has perfect (AKA superhuman) bodies. What's aiding them? The fact that when they die, the AIR ITSELF takes on their cause ('cause the infection is airborne) and turns the offenders into his comrades.